# Leaflet / Progressive Web App - quick turnaround on tile 404 (perhaps using Workbox)?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, workbox

I have a Leaflet map with two sets of my own tiles (this is for a campground map).  The tiles are limited to the boundaries of the camp, so I don't have a lot of them.  I've built a progressive web app (using Workbox for caching) and got to thinking about the following situation:

There are a significant number of requests for non-existent tiles, where the `TileLayer` knows to serve a default tile via `errorTileUrl`, which means quite a few 404 requests even when offline (since the tiles won't be in the cache).  However, this seems a bit silly to me because I *know* which tiles should be present ahead of time, so I should be able to prevent the off-map 404s (looking at about 20 failed requests at start up).

I do need to be able to show (blank) off-map tiles because I can't guarantee orientation/geometry of the full-screen map on the device.

My primary question is: is it worth worrying about this?  The app works as is now; just trying to make it a bit more network-efficient.

If so, one option I had considered is creating a new `workbox.router` route to handle calls to retrieve tiles and just quickly return a 404 if it's not in the list, otherwise go to cache/network.  Or is there something I'm missing in Leaflet (or a plug in) that already handles this?

Thanks for thoughts and ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to specify available tiles of your Leaflet Tile Layer on a rectangular area and a zoom range, using options:

- [`bounds`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#gridlayer-bounds): If set, tiles will only be loaded inside the set `LatLngBounds`.
- [`minNativeZoom`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#gridlayer-minnativezoom): Minimum zoom number the tile source has available. If it is specified, the tiles on all zoom levels lower than `minNativeZoom` will be loaded from `minNativeZoom` level and auto-scaled.
- [`maxNativeZoom`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#gridlayer-maxnativezoom): Maximum zoom number the tile source has available. If it is specified, the tiles on all zoom levels higher than `maxNativeZoom` will be loaded from `maxNativeZoom` level and auto-scaled.

If your available tiles do not fill a rectangular area, you can provide dummy tiles to fill the uncovered area. Using a service worker router can help in redirecting to a common dummy tile in cache indeed.

For the outside area, you could just use the container background. Or if you really want a similar effect as a Tile Layer, use dummy ones that point to a common dummy / "no tile available" constant url template.

Comment: Aha.  I had a map bounds set but didn't have a TileLayer bounds set (I missed that in the documentation because I didn't look under the inherited properties from GridLayer).  Let me try that out and if it works I'll accept this as an answer.